# bluetooth is not showing any devices on freshly installed ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, realtek

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e3]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8852be
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b85c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b760 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What is the BT device?

Comment: mobile, realme earbuds

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: please check the now

Comment: Please add output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`.

Comment: here is the link of output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XBFp6pNrfP/

Comment: It looks like the device isn't supported yet properly. You can report a bug to Launchpad.

Comment: ok thanks buddy :)

Comment: search Github and answer will show.
https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be
https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be_bt

Comment: It would be useful to describe what the link will require to build the driver.

Answer (score 2):

Running below command will fix the issue in Ubuntu 20.04 for Realtek rtl8852be_bt. No need to change ID as mentioned in Github Readme.

```
git clone https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be_bt.git
cd rtl8852be_bt
lsusb
make
sudo make install
reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a temporary solution because `btusb.c` in 5.15 and newer kernel haven't support your devices yet.
You can see solution on https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be_bt

### Usage

#### 1. Check your Bluetooth Device

```
$ lsusb
$ Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0bda:4853 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
```

#### 2. Modify/Add your USB DEVICE in btusb.c

[Modify Here](https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be_bt/blob/5.15/btusb.c#L424)

```
/* Realtek 8852BE Bluetooth devices */
{ USB_DEVICE(0x0bda, 0x4853), .driver_info = BTUSB_REALTEK |
               BTUSB_WIDEBAND_SPEECH },

// USB_DEVICE(0x____ , 0x____) is your ID name which shows in lsusb command
```

#### 3. Save and Build

```
#Turn off your Security Boot in BIOS

make
sudo make install
reboot
```

Comment: thanks for the solution now devices are visible but they get disconnected just after connected.

Answer (score 0):

because you don't have the bluetooth driver installed.Find the driver that matches your Bluetooth model at this website:
https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be_bt  ,Follow the official tutorial.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).